# Unable to change data source in Crystal reports 9

Tags: crystal-reports, asp-classic

I have a report set up on our test environment which uses a datasource called DEFAULT, which is also the name of the datasource on the client's production server. (Both are ODBC)

The databases in our test environment are called systemname_clientname but on site they are simply systemname.

I modified a report for the client and put it onsite then changed the datasource to the client version (DEFAULT.systemname) but the report keeps throwing errors saying that the object systemname_clientname.dbo.table does not exist.

I can't seem to make it realise that it is no longer pointing at the systemname_clientname database.

This is using Crystal Reports 9 and the reports are launched using an ASP page written in VBScript.

Google has been most unhelpful and my co-workers are equally stumped, can anybody offer some help here?

Comment: How did you change the data source? Do you mean by Database->Set Datasource location or through code?

Comment: Database -> Set Datasource location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database->Set Datasource Location has a bug in Crystal XI at least, maybe other versions.
Select the database and then updating doesn't update the source of every table.

If you expand the properties of each table you will see that it's still pointing at the old data source.

Try updating the data source for each table one by one.

Yes, it is tedious, sorry.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this.  Right clicking a table name doesn't give me anything I can modify.

Comment: In Database->Set Datasource location, click the plus next to the table name to expand it, then expand properties, you will see "Catalog: " followed by the wrong catalogue. Click the table name, then find the table in the "Replace with:" list and click update.

Comment: Ah nice, that looks good.  Thanks a lot, I bloody hate Crystal.

Comment: I assure you you're not alone. Just wait until you have 50 or so reports with 40 odd tables that you have to swap around. It takes forever.

Comment: Someone just marked this up, so an addendum. I find this problem is massively reduced by using a single stored procedures instead of letting crystal assemble the queries. Then you only have one datasource to update.

Comment: For me, updating the Datasource Location didn't work until I updated the connection while one of the tables was expanded (i.e., could see the Catalog). I wasn't able to directly edit the Catalog for an individual table in any way that I could find.

Comment: Two years after, I'm stuck on same issue. Not the answer nor the comments have helped me. I'm using Crystal Reports 11 under WinXP. I'm still getting the error `Failed to retrieve data from the database. Details: 08004:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Database 'my_database_name' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. [Database Vendor Code: 911]` Any other recommendation?